# Append project id from project context to JIRA web-item url

Tags: java, bitbucket, jira, confluence

I am working on a JIRA plugin that adds additional configuration to the JIRA project. I've added a web-item link to the project configuration page that links to a servlet. The problem I am running into is appending the project id as a query string to the URL. According to the [Atlassian cloud developer documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/concepts/context-parameters.html), JIRA supports project.id, project.key context parameters. However, the snippet below appends my project ID from the pom.xml file instead of the currently selected project.

```
<web-item>
...
    <link linkId="myproject-config-link">/plugins/servlet/myproject/admin?pid=${project.id}</link>   
    <context>project</context>
</web-item>
```

I have two questions: is what I am trying to do achievable and are the object keys (project.key, issue.key, comment.key, etc.) unique?

Comment: ${project.key} appends the value to the target URL correctly. As long as it is unique, I could work around the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/14194785/how-to-show-servlet-in-project-administration-panel), the solution is:

```
admin/pid=${helper.projectObject.id}&amp;key=${project.key}
```